# NavigationController not loading view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4.3

I'm using xCode 4.3.2 and started a blank application.

I have a navigation controller and a simple logincontroller. I want the login controller to be my root view so it is this first thing that a user does when they login.

I'm using the following code and when I run the application it displays a black screen. I put in logging in the LoginViewController.m->ViewDidLoad and it is being run is there something im doing wrong the LoginViewController.xib is very simple it just contains a button right now that will switch to a tab view controller once I figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        UIViewController *loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginController];



        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
        [self.window makeKeyWindow];


        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: try `self.window.rootViewController = navigationController` instead of adding the nav controller's view as a subview in window.

Comment: @nielsbot I tried that still getting a black screen. I also tried self.window.rootViewController = loginController; and had the same problem. Does this mean the problem is in my LoginViewController???

Comment: could be.. might want to make sure `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` are being called on your view controller, and check the frame of your view and whether its superview ≠ nil

Comment: Both viewDidAppear, and viewWillAppear are never hit... how do I check its superview ?

Comment: `assert( view.superview )` but this won't be set until after viewDidAppear: is called. Note: It's `-viewDidAppear:`, _not_ `-viewDidAppear`

Comment: @nielsbot initWithNibName and viewDidload are hit but then nothing happens, for checking viewDidAppear i just did    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
} Did you mean something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right:

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

change it to this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Comment: Still only displays a blank screen.

Comment: Then comment out almost all the code and just do self.window.rootViewController = loginController;, and I'm going to guess that will be black too meaning something is wrong with that login controller - the nib name is misspelled, or nib is not included in project, etc.